# Unity 2D: How to make player grab a ledge, swing and jump to another

Tags: unity, 2d, joints

Since I'm not a native speaker, it's hard to explain in english what I want to achieve, so I'm gonna use a couple of images... basically I want to make an interaction of this type:

[image]

in a 2D game, so it should be something like this (forgive me for the quality, but I'm not a designer as you can see :D):

[image]

What should I do? Currently I'm looking at 2D Physics Joints, but I'm not sure about which one is the most appropriate and how should I configure my objects... in my mind I think that the ledges should have a trigger collider that once the player jumps and enters in the collider area, a joint is dynamically attached (but which one and against which object... the player? The ledge? Both?)... how should I make the player swinging forward and backward once hooked to the ledge? I'm really confused :/

Comment: This answer will hopefully clear the confusion [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40302/how-do-i-detect-ledges](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40302/how-do-i-detect-ledges). The technique is pretty much the same in both 3d as 2d.